# Is there a software that can create virtual monitors from a single physical monitor?

Tags: display, virtualization, multi-monitor, duplicate-display

The question really says it all. I'm looking to see if there's software that can divide a single monitor into multiple virtual monitors. It's something I've often wanted, but never have been able to find.

I'm asking specifically for Windows 10.

Comment: Is the [virtual desktops feature](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-multiple-desktops-windows-10) what you're looking for?

Comment: Or something like virtuawin (https://virtuawin.sourceforge.net) also works for winows 10, at least version 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it exist. DisplayFusion I believe is the leading software solution for taking 1 single monitor and subdividing it into multiple virtual monitors.

These 'virtual desktops' are not to be confused with other virtual desktops created by software such as virtuawin, dexpot and windows virtual desktops.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I had yet to find any software that did this and virtual desktops isn't really what I was looking for.